# IndexOutOfBoundsException in onItemClick ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, indexoutofboundsexception

I have simple BaseAdatper with array of object. Also I have listView. Adatper is included to listView with `setAdatper()` method.

I have onItemClick Listener on listView. I received:

> ```
> Fatal Exception: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
> Invalid index 0, size is 0
> ```

I don't understand why. Because it should work `onItemClick` if adapter is empty. It looks like on listView displayed items but if I called `getItem()` in `onItemClick` adapter is empty. Why?

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, final int position, long id) {
                    UserModel user = (UserModel) listView.getAdapter().getItem(position);

                    showFragment(UserDetailsFragment.newInstance(user.getId(), new UserDetailsFragment.OnFollowListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFollow(boolean value) {
                            ((UserModel) listView.getAdapter().getItem(position)).setFollowedBy(value);
                            view.findViewById(R.id.following_user).setSelected(value);
                        }
                    }), UserDetailsFragment.TAG);
                }
        });
```

Comment: Possible is this line, `((UserModel) listView.getAdapter().getItem(position)).setFollowedBy(value);` because you are getting an item from the adapter and you have no items in the adapter

Comment: yeah, but this shouldn't be possible (how can you click an item when there are NO items?)

Comment: try to compare position before acces item.

Comment: Yes it can be possible, have you added in your adapter method `getItem()` to return the object `UserModel`? And make sure you are passing the objects to your adapter.

Comment: Method `getItem()` is defined and returh the object. I think you are right with line: `((UserModel) listView.getAdapter().getItem(position)).setFollowedBy(value);` Because it fire when probably adapter is empty. But why. Thank you I will check

Comment: I assume this is a custom adapter right? so instead of **UserModel user = (UserModel) listView.getAdapter().getItem(position);** why don't you use the same arraylist/string array you are using to feed the listview adapter? like 

 ***UserModel user = arraylist.get(position)***

then proceed from there

Comment: Yes it is custom adapter. This code is from my Fragment. I don't have arraylist of objects for adapter in Fragment. I received from GSON arrayList of object and I include to apater new list of object with Otto.

Comment: diogojme I removed line about you wrote. I use just final user object in `onFollow()` method. We will check if all be fine :)

Comment: Hello diogojme. I will check if user is null in `onFollow()` and all look fine. Thank you for help :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you overwrite method `getItem()`? And if so ,what's inside.

Comment: Yes. It return object from array adapter

Comment: If your listview has a headerview,you wouldn't get your own adapter.That may alse cause the problem.

Comment: Thx. I dont have headerview :)

Answer (score 0):

**First:** If your array list is Empty,means in your list view contains no items. You don't have chance to 'OnItemClick'.

**Second:** Please check in your adapter class by mistake u may get an object from Empty ArrayList please check. Following  conditions in 'getCount()' and 'getItem(int position)' methods for reference check bellow code.

```
 class TestAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<Object> arrayList;

    // Do your Stuff

    public TestAdapter(ArrayList<Object> arrayList) {
        // Do your Stuff
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return arrayList != null ? arrayList.size() : 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return (arrayList != null && arrayList.size() >= position) ? arrayList.get(position) : null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // Do your Stuff
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Do your Stuff
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: After change of your array list immediately you need to call  update(); . I think this cause of 'IndexOutOfBoundsException'

make a 'update()' method  call in 'add(S item)' as well as  'clear()' methods